# Express Get Routes not working receiving 404

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a very basic node express application and other then the root route, it does not work. So when I load the page, the home ejs loads just fine. I can even change the ejs template that it is rendering. However, if I put domain.com/about or have an anchor tag from the homepage to /about or /services or anything else, it does not work. I am on an ubuntu 18.04 server running nginx. The app is on another route but these routes aren't working either.

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render('home');
});

app.get("/services", function(req, res) {
  res.render('services');
});

app.get("/contact", function(req, res) {
  res.render('contact');
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res) {
  res.render('about');
});
```

Comment: Where do you save the ejs views ?

Comment: i have a views folder under my root directory

Answer (score 0):

This issue was on the NGINX side.

I had to remove the line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Once I removed this from the config file. The routes work as expected.